# Data extracted from Acces to Excel is automatically getting over to extra sheet than the defined sheet

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am trying to get some data extracted from MS Access to Excel sheet which is a kind of already defined template. For example , i use an excel file with say one sheet named **Result** (with some pre-defined data) as a source file and then i copy the same to an output file. Then some OutputTable from MS Access is extracted in output file using **DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet** with explicitly mentioned to get extracted in Result sheet . The data is coming fine but the sheet Result is not used though an extra sheet named **Result1** gets created with same data as OutputTable of Ms Access.

Code i am using is mentioned below:

```
    SourceFile = CurrentProject.Path & "\Template\" & "Input_Template.xlsx"
    DestinFile = CurrentProject.Path & "\Output\" & "Output_" & sDateTimeStamp & ".xlsx"
    FileCopy SourceFile, DestinFile
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "OutputTable", DestinFile, False, "Result"
```

I have these folders Template (having Input_Template.xlsx file) and Output folder created on my system under same path where the Database is placed.

Could anyone tell if i'm doing it in wrong way or is there any configuration required or i might be missing something. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank You!!! 
Honey

Comment: Supposedly - the last argument "Result" should not be used when you export - it's supposed to give you an error, so I;m not sure how it works for you even the way it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TransferSpreadsheet` is not suitable for exporting to pre-formatted template. Use `CopyFromRecordset` method from Excel library instead. Example below will dump content of `OutputTable` to "Result" spreadsheet of destination template file starting "B2" cell.

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWork As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim rsExportResults As Recordset

Set rsExportResults = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("OutputTable")

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWork = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(DestinFile)
Set xlSheet = xlWork.Sheets("Result")

xlSheet.Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rsExportResults
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey. This is one of the approach to extract the way m trying here. But there was a project i worked before and this transferspread was workign fine. not sure what i'm missin here.